# Service Worker file and an offline mode

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Do I understand correctly that a server worker file in a PWA should not be cached by a PWA? As I understand, once registered, installed and activated, it exits as an entity separate from a page in a browser environment and gets reloaded by the browser once a new version is found (I am omitting details that are not important here). So I see no reason to cache a service worker file. Browser kind of caching it by storing it in memory (or somewhere). I think caching a service worker file will complicate discovery of its code update and will bring no benefits.

However, if a service worker is not cached, there will be an error trying to retrieve it while refreshing a page that registers it in an offline mode because the service worker file is not available when the network is down.

What's the best way to eliminate this error? Or should I cache a service worker file? What's the most efficient strategy here?

I was doing some reading on PWA but found no clear explanation of the matter. Please help me with your advice if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. Never cache service-worker.js.

To avoid the error that comes from trying to register without connectivity simply check the connection state from window.navigator.onLine and skip calling register if offline.

You can listen for network state changes and call registration at a later point in time if you want.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. It all makes sense now. Checking a connection state should be a good guard against trying to load a service worker file while offline.

Comment: `window.navigator.onLine` returns true if you have a connection, but it doesn't mean you have a connection to the Internet. For example, your PC/laptop is connected to a router, this method returns true even though the router doesn't have connection to the Internet.